# Water from fridge tastes bad and now fridge smells

Tags: water, repair, refrigerator, replacement, filter

My daughter called and sad the water from the fridge tasted bad and now the fridge smells as well.  Could this be because we need to change the filter?  I spoke to one repairman and he said yes.  If I replace the filter how long will it take before the water begins to taste good and the fridge stop smelling?

Comment: Sounds like a smart step #1, especially if the filter needs changing anyway. You would then need to clear the water downstream of the filter, right? Throw away any ice from an icemaker. There's a coiled up water line in my fridge for chilling the water, where I imagine some analogous reservoir is common (lots of surface area and enough volume for a couple glasses of water). Flush that water too. And I'd sniff the  old filter for confirmation. Smash it open and look if smell can't confirm. Also clean the ice reservoir while it's free of ice.

Comment: The smelly fridge sounds like a red herring. The water and fridge interior shouldn't impact each other. The ice maker is the one spot where they cross, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the filter should have an almost immediate effect on improving the taste of the water unless there is some sediment in the water line. To correct the problem of the fridge smelling, you'll have to dump out all the ice cubes and possibley wipe down the items in the freezer. You should also discard the first few batches of ice made after changing the filter.